# Repair man lied for you to his company to help you with warranty

Tags: halacha-theory, gezel-stealing, parnassah-livelihood

Imagine a washing machine (etc) repair man comes round to fix it on a warranty claim. When they find out what it is, it turns out to be something that's not covered on warranty. Later you find out they wrote something else on their report in order that you shouldn't get charged for the call out, because they were trying to be nice.

Reporting him and owning up might get him fired or severely penalised at work, but there might be a halachic imperative to do so because of fraud/theft.

What should one do?

Comment: You owe the manufacturer the cost of the repair. Sending them the money anonymously may seem suspicious. So buy something else from them where you estimate their profit will cover that cost. Leave the repairman alone. The Talmud says it's better to break a commandment with good intentions than to follow a commandment with evil intentions.

Comment: This question is discussed here. https://torah.org/learning/business-halacha-5757-vol1no31/

Comment: @Chatzkel thanks it does in part, but it doesn't make any mention of the moral dilemma of the repair man and his job/livelihood. That could be taken to mean that there is no such consideration, what do you think?

Comment: I guess you should tell him to return it himself somehow, and if he refuses, try to see if there’s a way to do it discretely. However keeping it isn’t an option